# What is this cabinet?

Tags: cabinets

Just moved into this house and have this old cabinet above the workbench. Does anyone know it's original purpose or is it just general tool storage?
[image: cabinet]

Comment: The purpose of _any_ cabinet is determined by the user. I'm guessing this one held a Beanie Babies collection. Were it mine I'd probably have it full of model airplane tools and supplies. (My real tools are in the garage.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tool/parts cabinet.

Depending how it is set up can hold many hand tools and/or parts.

If that was original use or was repurposed from a tv/glassware cabinet, will be hard to tell without knowing, but does look it was made for a tool cabinet.  A nice one also.

Comment: Yep- built one just like this for my dad a few years ago. Hanging tools, bins for small parts, etc inside, and keeps the dust out and the clutter contained.

Comment: The things in the upper part of the door we can see the inside of are to hold handsaws by the handle. Front part of it turns to keep the handle from slipping off. Can't see any detail of the rest of the tool racks.